# contar dos campos de una tabla en php sql

Tags: php, html, sql

tengo una tabla que se llama **matriculas_2018** y dos campos uno de **cursos** y el otro de **especialidad**.

quiero poner un contador que me diga cuantos alumnos del **curso TERCERO MEDIO** corresponden a la **especialidad ADMINISTRACION**  y otro que me haga la misma función pero con la **especialidad de CONTABILIDAD**

---

> espero me puedan ayudar.. gracias

---

Comment: Qué has intentado? cuál es tu error?
Lee [como preguntar es stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Qué has intentado? Aquí se resuelven dudas, no problemas enteros. Por otro lado, faltan datos, no has puesto donde están los `alumnos`.

Answer (score 1):

Así debería funcionar:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IF(cursos = 'TERCERO MEDIO' and especialidad = 'ADMINISTRACION ',1,0)) as suma_administracion
    SUM(IF(cursos = 'TERCERO MEDIO' and especialidad = 'CONTABILIDAD ',1,0)) as suma_contabilidad
FROM matriculas_2018;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sin quiere consultar por una especialidad y curso especifico sería así:

`SELECT CONUT(*) AS cantidad_contabilidad FROM matriculas_2018 WHERE curso LIKE '%TERCERO MEDIO%' AND especialidad LIKE '%CONTABILIDAD%';`

Pero si quiere que cuente de cada especialidad, lo que tiene es que agrupar

`SELECT especialidad , CONUT(*) AS cantidad_contabilidad FROM matriculas_2018 WHERE curso LIKE '%TERCERO MEDIO%' GROUP BY especialidad;`